# How to find the install program path from jsp?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, activexobject, ocx

When user visit my website and click the button,I want to start the Postman.exe.So I have to find the  Postman install path.I have used the ocx and regedit commond to find the install path.But if the program do not write the infomation to the registry,How to find and start the program? Can I use the bat command?

```
function exec () {  
var command;  
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
try
{
    command = shell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Directory\\shell\\RadiAnt\\Icon");
}
catch(e)
{
    if(window.confirm("你可能还没有安装Radiant，请下载安装")){
        //alert("确定");
         window.location.href="jspView/radiantsetup32312921.exe";
         return false;
     }else{
        return false;
    }
}//执行exe程序
    window.oldOnError = window.onerror;  
    window._command = command;  
    window.onerror = function (err) {  
  if (err.indexOf('utomation') != -1) {  
    alert('命令' + window._command + ' 已经被用户禁止！');   
    return true;  
   }  
   else return false;  
 };  
 var wsh = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');  
 if (wsh)  
 wsh.Run("\""+command); 
 window.onerror = window.oldOnError;
}
```

Comment: The tool is to control the video camera, and my web is integrating this function,I want the user  to install the tool,but the install path may be different by user's choices.

Comment: In the tool,it have already do some statistics for the monitor data,so I want to use it and do not do the thing two times.

Comment: Unless your user is the only one using this script on his/her local desktop with IE/HTA only then continue with your current approach, else I would suggest you to stop and go for other option. Your current approach has serious security issues from user point of view

Comment: Yes,the user is asked to  use IE because of OCX contrel.